# How to display navigation properties in a MVC/EF WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, webgrid

Lets say, I have the following model

```
public class MyObject {
    public String id { get; set; }
    public virtual Organisation organisation { get; set; }
    public int organisationId { get; set; }
}

public class Organisation {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public String name { get; set; }
}
```

I created a controller with a DbContext (ServiceContext) having a DbSet myObjects

```
public ActionResult Index() {
    ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext();
    context.myObjects.Include(o => o.organisation).ToList();
    return View(myObjects);
}
```

And a view

```
@model Enumerable<MyObject>
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model);
}
<div>
    @grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```

The corresponding WebGrid is displayed but I dont know how to display the **Organization name property** as a grid column. By default only the organizationId field is displayed.

Any ideas? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working with the following code in the view (so simple ...)

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column(columnName:"organisation.name"),
    )
)
```